# Newbie question related to Flutter StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I just started using Flutter, and was testing the sample counter app created with "flutter create counter"

First thing I wanted to try, was to move the counter logic to another Widget, so I tried this code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: CounterWidget(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: // How to call the widget increment funcion???,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterWidget({
    Key? key,
    void onCount,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CounterWidget> createState() => _CounterWidgetState();
}

class _CounterWidgetState extends State<CounterWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    _counter++;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
        ),
        Text(
          '$_counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

But then I realized that now I don't know hot to call the `incrementCounter` function of the widget each time the button is pressed.

What would be the right way to accomplish this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the other way around. Create a stateless widget Counter. Store the value in HomePage and on each press setstate with a new counter value passed to Counter.

This way Even the floating button could be a separate stateless widget with `final VoidCallback increment;` parameter. And keep the incrementing void in the HomePage.

```
int increment() {
setState((){counter++})
}
```

Then create floating button as a separate widget with

```
FloatingButton(increase: increment)
```

Now you have 3 widgets, 1 stateful with dynamic information and 2 stateless where one has some behavior that impacts the other stateless widget by passing new information to it on `setState`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. 
I noticed that I could solve it by putting the counter variable outside of the counter widget as you mentioned, but is that the way it is supposed to be done? Cant the counter logic be inside of the counter widget?

Comment: As a Flutter developer of 3 years I've only done it like that (if the project is simple enough) mostly all logic is pushed as far away as possible using tools like bloc (https://bloclibrary.dev/#/). If you really want it to work as you described I'd need more time to come up with a solution.

Comment: Theoretically you could override initState in Counter widget to increment counter every time it's built and call setState in a parent widget to force rebuilding of all widgets inside it but that would be the most inefficent code I'd ever seen ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `incrementCounter` function in main class and pass it to `CounterWidget` ,like this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CounterWidget(
          counter: _counter,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterWidget({Key? key, required this.counter}) : super(key: key);
  final int counter;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'You have pushed the button this many times:',
        ),
        Text(
          '$counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm too used to other languages, but I don't like that the counter lives outside of the counter widget; 
Couldn't it be encapsulated inside of the counter widget

Comment: Your action is in main class, some how you should notify CounterWidget that counter is changing and from my opinion the only way is rebuilding  CounterWidget.